# Java GPA Calculator Loop

Tags: java, loops, calculator

So the whole objective of this code is to figure out the GPA of a semester. It asks the user for the semester name (ie. Fall 2014), Course title, credits, and grade. It lists these information into a text file with the calculate GPA.

I can't seem to figure out how to make it so when you say "y" (yes) to the prompt, "Would you like to calculate for another semester (y/n)" it'd create another new text file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class GpaCalcPeter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    processInput();
}

static void processInput() throws Exception {

    String yOrN;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String className, semester, semesterFile;
    int credits, grade, totalCredits = 0, gradePoints = 0, n=0;
    double gpa;
    char choice = 'y';

    System.out.println ("Enter the semester: ");
    semester = in.nextLine();
    semester = semester.toLowerCase();
    semester = semester.replaceAll(" ", "");

    semesterFile = semester + ".txt";       
    PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(new File(semesterFile));

    while (choice != 'n') {

        System.out.println("Enter the course title: ");
        className = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of credits: ");
        credits = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the grade (A=4, B=3 etc.)");
        grade = in.nextInt();

        writer.printf("%s - %d" +" credits. Grade: %d", 
            className, credits, grade);
        writer.println("");

        gradePoints = gradePoints + grade * credits;
        totalCredits = totalCredits +credits;
        n = n + 1;

        in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another course? (y/n)");
        yOrN = in.nextLine();
        choice = yOrN.charAt(0);

        if (choice != 'y') {
            gpa = gradePoints / (float) totalCredits;
            System.out.printf("Overall GPA: %.2f", gpa);
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Would you like to calculate for another semester (y/n)");
            yOrN = in.nextLine();
            choice = yOrN.charAt(0);

        }


    }

    gpa = gradePoints / (float) totalCredits;
    writer.printf("GPA: %.2f", gpa);
    writer.close();
}

}
```

Comment: So would I add a while loop inside the one I already have?

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw the inner loop. `in.next` would be a good choice

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using `in.next();` instead of `in.nextLine();`
Otherwise, your code work fine in my env.